# No internet in Android emulator after Charles proxy setup

Tags: android-emulator, charles-proxy

After setup from this [link](https://apiumtech.com/blog/charles-proxy-in-android-emulator/) my Charles Proxy seems to be working but there is no internet access on android emulator. I'm using nexus 5X API 22. Any advices are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty obvious but... did you ensure Charles Proxy is already opened before starting the emulator?

Being that the case... If I where you I would try the following:

1. Start the emulator as normal, without any proxy parameters, to ensure internet connection is OK and make focus on CharlesProxy being the real problem.
2. Add the proxy configuration on the WiFi settings from the Android configuration (not the emulator one).
3. If everything is ok, proceed with https configuration as explained in the CharlesProxy documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. It's because Charles fails to proxy a lot of requests. It's visible in Charles logs as a lot Failes 200 CONNECT requests. Probably one of them is Android ping which checks real Internet availability.

Answer (score 0):

From charles menu on top:

1. Select Tools
2. Uncheck whitelist